# Paypal Sandbox Token Expired

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

Previously this was working all right, but I think paypal iv has done some changes and now I can't figure out how to get it working. I always get this response :

"This Express Checkout session has expired. Token value is no longer valid."

```
array(9) {
["TIMESTAMP"]=>
string(28) "2013%2d01%2d30T16%3a47%3a32Z"
["CORRELATIONID"]=>
string(13) "1c384dff48bb7"
["ACK"]=>
string(7) "Failure"
["VERSION"]=>
string(6) "76%2e0"
["BUILD"]=>
string(7) "4181146"
["L_ERRORCODE0"]=>
string(5) "10411"
["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]=>
string(54) "This%20Express%20Checkout%20session%20has%20expired%2e"
["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=>
string(103) "This%20Express%20Checkout%20session%20has%20expired%2e%20   %20Token%20value%20is%20no%20longer%20valid%2e"
["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]=>
string(5) "Error"
}
```

Comment: Helps if you show the code performing the action prior to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I encountered this error during testing, it was because I was redirecting the customer back to Express Checkout using the same token that they just used to complete a payment. Ensure that you aren't accidentally sending the customer back or reusing a previously acquired token. Remember that they expire after 30 minutes - it's best just to set a new token any time the customer returns to your site and then attempts to redirect back to PayPal.

The loop in my application was caused by a bug in my return page's code that was sending the customer back to PayPal via a 301 redirect instead of acknowledging a completed payment. As far as PayPal was concerned, that token was done with, and they thought they had got rid of me. But when the behavior activated in my browser, because I was using 301 redirects I never noticed that I was even returning to my site before going back to PayPal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Iv just the same code not using sandbox and its working :) but in sandbox give me token expired lol